# Does Korn shell have an equivalent feature to Bash's command_not_found_handle?

Tags: bash, ksh, prompt

And does Korn shell have an equivalent to PROMPT_COMMAND?

In Bash, I'm able to make function calls with a parameter when a single input word matches a regular expression. Can Korn shell do this?

Let's say ksh88.

For example, in Bash, I can call a function by entering any single word in the command line matching a regular expression by doing:

```
command_not_found_handle()
{

    if [[ $1 =~ ^[A-Z]+\.[0-4]+$ ]]; then
        callFunction "$1"
        return 222;
    else
        printf "command not found: %s\n" "$1" >&2
        return 127
    fi
}
```

and

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $? -eq 222 ]] && callFunction'
```

Can something similar be done in ksh88?

Comment: What "KornShell"? ksh93, pdksh & co (mksh, OpenBSD's ksh), the real ksh88, zsh masquerading as ksh?

Comment: It seems you've asked two (related?) questions: one about a ksh PROMPT_COMMAND and another about calling a function based on the first parameter. Are they tightly related or are these two separate questions?

Comment: For the `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you can simply put a command substitution in `PS1`: `PS1='$(echo Beware, the prompt is going to be printed!! >&2)the Ksh$ '`

Comment: @mosvy, or use `${ cmd; }` (in ksh93 / ksh2020) to avoid the subshell, or set the `PS1.get` discipline. For `command_not_found_handler`, you can probably use a `DEBUG` trap.

Comment: I don't have any historical ksh88 to check how its `DEBUG` trap worked, but AFAIK pdksh and derivatives don't support the `DEBUG` trap. Also, your bash trick looks broken, what will happen when the a command like `E.1` is run from a pipeline or command substitution?

Answer (score 1):

`ksh93` can also support `PROMPT_COMMAND` with a discipline function (via [dgk](https://www.mail-archive.com/ast-users@lists.research.att.com/msg01030.html)).

```
function PS1.get 
{
    integer exitval=$?
    eval .sh.value=$($PROMPT_COMMAND)'$PS1'
    return $exitval
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`ksh88` already has something better than that bash method.

There is a special `trap` condition called `ERR`. So try this:

```
trap 'echo bla' ERR
false
```

and you see that `echo bla` is executed.

BTW: This also works with `bash`...